# Automating data import from excel sheet into SQL server using python

Tags: sql-server, excel, python-3.x

I need to import my data - which is in excel sheet- into SQL Server I can do that manually but it's really time-consuming. Is there any way I can automate this whole process using Python?
Any suggestions.